# Searching for duplicate records within a text file where the duplicate is determined by only two fields

Tags: python

First, Python Newbie; be patient/kind.

Next, once a month I receive a large text file (think 7 Million records) to test for duplicate values.  This is catalog information.  I get 7 fields, but the two I'm interested in are a supplier code and a full orderable part number.  To determine if the record is dupliacted, I compress all special characters from the part number (except . and #) and create a compressed part number.  The test for duplicates becomes the supplier code and compressed part number combination.  This part is fairly straight forward.  Currently, I am just copying the original file with 2 new columns (compressed part and duplicate indicator).  If the part is a duplicate, I put a "YES" in the last field.  Now that this is done, I want to be able to go back (or better yet, at the same time) to get the previous record where there was a supplier code/compressed part number match.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
# Compress Full Part to a Compressed Part
# and Check for Duplicates on Supplier Code
# and Compressed Part combination
import sys
import re
import time
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
start=time.time()

try:
   file1 = open("C:\Accounting\May Accounting\May.txt", "r")
except IOError:
   print >> sys.stderr, "Cannot Open Read File"
   sys.exit(1)
try:
   file2 = open(file1.name[0:len(file1.name)-4] + "_" + "COMPRESSPN.txt", "a")
except IOError:
   print >> sys.stderr, "Cannot Open Write File"
   sys.exit(1)

hdrList="CIGSUPPLIER|FULL_PART|PART_STATUS|ALIAS_FLAG|ACQUISITION_FLAG|COMPRESSED_PART|DUPLICATE_INDICATOR"
file2.write(hdrList+chr(10))
lines_seen=set()
affirm="YES"

records = file1.readlines()
for record in records:
   fields = record.split(chr(124))
      if fields[0]=="CIGSupplier":
         continue                  #If incoming file has a header line, skip it
   file2.write(fields[0]+"|"),     #Supplier Code
   file2.write(fields[1]+"|"),     #Full_Part
   file2.write(fields[2]+"|"),     #Part Status
   file2.write(fields[3]+"|"),     #Alias Flag
   file2.write(re.sub("[$\r\n]", "", fields[4])+"|"),     #Acquisition Flag
   file2.write(re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z.#]", "", fields[1])+"|"),   #Compressed_Part
   dupechk=fields[0]+"|"+re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z.#]", "", fields[1])
      if dupechk not in lines_seen:
         file2.write(chr(10))
         lines_seen.add(dupechk)
      else:
         file2.write(affirm+chr(10))

print "it took", time.time() - start, "seconds."        
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
file2.close()
file1.close()
```

It runs in less than 6 minutes, so I am happy with this part, even if it is not elegant.  Right now, when I get my results, I import the results into Access and do a self join to locate the duplicates.  Loading/querying/exporting results in Access a file this size takes around an hour, so I would like to be able to export the matched duplicates to another text file or an Excel file.

Confusing enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider building a dictionary mapping `(supplier_number, compressed_part_number)` tuples to data structures (nested lists perhaps, or instances of a custom class for improved readability & maintainability) holding information on line numbers for the lines the records matching the key tuple appear in your file plus possibly the complete records themselves.

This would end up putting all the data from the file into a large in-memory dictionary, which might or might not be a problem depending on your requirements; if you skip the actual records and only hold line numbers, the dictionary will be much smaller.

You can then iterate over the entries in the dictionary spitting out the duplicates to a file as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sort the entries in the input file first. Maybe it will consume too much memory, but you should first try to read all input in memory, sort this based  upon the value of `dupechk` and then you can iterate over all entries and easily see if there are two or more identical records. Because identical records are grouped, it is easy to output just those records.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more efficient/feasible for the large files you are dealing with:

1. [Sort](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576755-sorting-big-files-the-python-26-way/) the file based on the supplier code and compressed part number - dump it to a [temporary file](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html). I don't think it is worth actually tacking on the compressed part number, just compute it from the full part number when needed. However, that is pure conjecture and definitely deserves some quick benchmarking.
2. Iterate through the temporary file (might want to take advantage of '[with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)'). Check if current line's supplier code and compressed part number is identical to previous one - if it is, you have identified a duplicate. Handle as you see fit. Since the file is sorted you reduce the memory requirement of needing to store all the lines in memory to a set of consecutive identical lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are already reading the whole file into memory. You don't need to sort. Instead of a set, have a dict mapping `(supplier, compressed_pn)` to `line_number_last_seen - 1`. That way, when you discover a duplicate, you can output the two duplicate records immediately. This method requires only one pass over the file. You don't need to write a temporary file.

If you often have 3 or more records with the same key, you may wish to use an approach that maps the key to a list of line indices. At the end of reading the file, you iterate over the dictionary looking for lists with more than 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments:

1. Using `file.readlines` on a large file is wasteful - it's reading the entire file into memory. You should, instead, take advantage that a file is iterable, reading a single line at a time by default.
2. Your file format is basically a CSV, with a pipe instead of a comma as a separator. So, use the CSV module. The CSV is written in C and escapes most of the interpreted overhead. It also provides a nice iterable interface which also does not require reading the whole file into memory, either.
3. You should additionally use a `DictReader` from the `csv` module.  If the header is in the file, great, the class will parse it and use as the keys further on. If not, specify the header in the code. Either way, fields[0] is uninformative and error prone. fields["CIGSUPPLIER"] is much more self-documenting.
4. Just as with reading, use the `csv` module for writing. Again, you can specify the delimiter.
5. Don't use `file2.write(char(10))`. Use `file2.write('\n')`, and open your file appropriately. Alternatively, if you're using the `csv.writer` class, these become unnecessary.

Otherwise, your logic and flow looks alright. I'd overall advise against using the `chr(*)` calls, unless that character is truly unprintable. newlines and pipes are printable (or have supported escapes), and should be used as such.